Azure Container-App Post-Request with PDF-Upload returns "502 Bad Gateway", "507 Insufficient Storage" or "503 Service Unavailable"
I have a Azure Container-App containing an Docker Image of an Fast-API application that is supposed to alter an uploaded PDF and return back the altered PDF. On my localhost the application runs fine, however after deployment the Post-Request leads to the above responses. It says:
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
However, the simple Hello-World-Get-Request works just fine so that the deployment should have worked.
The Protocol Stream does not contain any useful information.
I am thankful for any help, since I am not super experienced using Azure.
main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, File, UploadFile  
import logging  
import io  
from app.redact_pdf import redact_pdf  
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse  
  
app = FastAPI()  
  
@app.post("/http_trigger")  
async def http_trigger(file: UploadFile = File(...), language: str = None):  
    logging.info('FastAPI HTTP trigger function processed a request.')  
  
    if file.content_type == 'application/pdf':  
        input_pdf_stream = io.BytesIO(await file.read())  
  
        if not language:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="The request does not contain language parameter.")  
  
        output_pdf_stream = redact_pdf(input_pdf_stream, language)  
          
        return StreamingResponse(  
            io.BytesIO(output_pdf_stream.read()),  
            media_type="application/pdf"  
        )  
    else:  
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="The request does not contain PDF data.")
    
@app.get("/hello")  
async def read_root():  
    return {"message": "hello world"}  

redact_pdf.py
import pymupdf
import re
import io
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
from flair.data import Sentence  
from flair.models import SequenceTagger  
  
def redact_pdf(input_pdf_stream, language):  
    if language not in ["EN", "DE"]:  
        raise ValueError("Invalid language selection. Please choose 'EN' for English or 'DE' for German.")  
   
    if language == "EN":  
        tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-english-large")  
    else:  
        tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-german-large")  
  Open PDF from BytesIO-Stream  
    doc = pymupdf.open("pdf", input_pdf_stream)  
  
    zip_code_pattern = re.compile(r'\b\d{5}\b')  # Beispiel: 12345  
    email_pattern = re.compile(r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b')  
  
    phone_patterns = [  
        re.compile(r'\b\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}\b'),  # 123-456-7890 oder 123 456 7890  
        re.compile(r'\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}\b'),    # (123) 456-7890  
        re.compile(r'\b\d{4}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}\b'),  # 1234-567-890  
    ]  
  
    for page_num in range(len(doc)):  
        page = doc.load_page(page_num)  
        text = page.get_text()  
    
        sentence = Sentence(text)  
        tagger.predict(sentence)  
   
        entities = [(entity.start_position, entity.end_position, entity.text) for entity in sentence.get_spans('ner') if entity.tag in ["PER", "ORG", "LOC"]]  
   
        for match in zip_code_pattern.finditer(text):  
            start, end = match.span()  
            entities.append((start, end, match.group()))  
    
        for pattern in phone_patterns:  
            for match in pattern.finditer(text):  
                start, end = match.span()  
                entities.append((start, end, match.group()))  
   
        for match in email_pattern.finditer(text):  
            start, end = match.span()  
            entities.append((start, end, match.group()))  
  
        print(entities)  
  
        for start, end, entity_text in entities:  
            search_results = page.search_for(entity_text)  
            if search_results:  
                for rect in search_results:  
                    page.add_redact_annot(rect, text="REDACTED", fill=(0, 0, 0))  
   
        page.apply_redactions()  
   
        pix = page.get_pixmap()  
        img = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.height, pix.width, pix.n)  
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    
        binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)  
  
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
  
        for cnt in contours:  
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)    
            if 30 < w < 400 and 5 < h < 150:   
                page.add_redact_annot(pymupdf.Rect(x, y, x+w, y+h), text="REDACTED", fill=(0, 0, 0))  
  
        page.apply_redactions()  
    
    output_pdf_stream = io.BytesIO()  
    doc.save(output_pdf_stream, garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)  
    output_pdf_stream.seek(0)  
  
    return output_pdf_stream

Dockerfile
# Start with the official Python image  
FROM python:3.9-slim  
  
# Set the working directory  
WORKDIR /app  
  
# Install system dependencies  
RUN apt-get update \  
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \  
    gcc \  
    build-essential \  
    libgl1-mesa-glx \  
    libglib2.0-0 \  
    && apt-get clean  
  
# Install python packages  
COPY requirements.txt .  
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt  
  
# Copy the application code  
COPY . .  
  
# Expose the port the app runs on  
EXPOSE 8000  
  
# Command to run the application  
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]


What is the approximate size of the uploaded PDF files?

The one was testiing has only 233kb. The app should be able to handle multiple requests at once.
The Container-App has 1 CPU Core and 2 GB of RAM. Are special ingress settings needed for uploads maybe?


PDF-Upload returns "502 Bad Gateway", "507 Insufficient Storage" or "503 Service Unavailable"


The error message you're seeing might be because your Azure Container App is running out of resources.
Scale the container to use more CPU and memory in the Azure portal.

I've tried your code, successfully deployed it to Azure Container Apps, and can see the redacted PDF successfully.
I made a few changes to your redact_pdf.py.

Added FastAPI to create an endpoint (/http_trigger) for handling PDF redaction requests.
I made the redaction code into a separate function (redact_pdf) and called it inside the FastAPI endpoint.

redact_pdf.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import io
app = FastAPI()
def redact_pdf(input_pdf_stream, language):
    import pymupdf
    import re
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from flair.data import Sentence
    from flair.models import SequenceTagger

    if language not in ["EN", "DE"]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid language selection. Please choose 'EN' for English")

    if language == "EN":
        tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-english-large")
    else:
        tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-german-large")

    doc = pymupdf.open("pdf", input_pdf_stream)

    zip_code_pattern = re.compile(r"\b\d{5}\b")
    email_pattern = re.compile(r"\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b")

    phone_patterns = [
        re.compile(r"\b\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}\b"),
        re.compile(r"\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}\b"),
        re.compile(r"\b\d{4}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}\b"),
    ]

    for page_num in range(len(doc)):
        page = doc.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text()

        sentence = Sentence(text)
        tagger.predict(sentence)

        entities = [
            (entity.start_position, entity.end_position, entity.text)
            for entity in sentence.get_spans("ner")
            if entity.tag in ["PER", "ORG", "LOC"]
        ]

        for match in zip_code_pattern.finditer(text):
            start, end = match.span()
            entities.append((start, end, match.group()))

        for pattern in phone_patterns:
            for match in pattern.finditer(text):
                start, end = match.span()
                entities.append((start, end, match.group()))

        for match in email_pattern.finditer(text):
            start, end = match.span()
            entities.append((start, end, match.group()))

        for start, end, entity_text in entities:
            search_results = page.search_for(entity_text)
            if search_results:
                for rect in search_results:
                    page.add_redact_annot(rect, text="REDACTED", fill=(0, 0, 0))

        page.apply_redactions()

        pix = page.get_pixmap()
        img = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.height, pix.width, pix.n)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for cnt in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            if 30 < w < 400 and 5 < h < 150:
                page.add_redact_annot(pymupdf.Rect(x, y, x + w, y + h), text="REDACTED", fill=(0, 0, 0))

        page.apply_redactions()

    output_pdf_stream = io.BytesIO()
    doc.save(output_pdf_stream, garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
    output_pdf_stream.seek(0)

    return output_pdf_stream

@app.post("/http_trigger")
async def redact_file(language: str = Form(...), file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    
    input_pdf_stream = io.BytesIO(await file.read())

    try:
        redacted_pdf_stream = redact_pdf(input_pdf_stream, language)
    except ValueError as e:
        return {"error": str(e)} 
    return StreamingResponse(redacted_pdf_stream, media_type="application/pdf")

I successfully deployed the application to Azure Container Apps and can view the redacted PDF after the POST request.


The one was testiing has only 233kb. The app should be able to handle multiple requests at once. The Container-App has 1 CPU Core and 2 GB of RAM. Are special ingress settings needed for uploads maybe?

You probably don't need special ingress settings for file uploads, but if you expect high traffic or large files, consider using auto-scaling.
